# Python - All the lines and line numbers in which string occurs in the input file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, keyword

I want to print all the lines in which a string occurs in the input file, along with the line numbers . So far I wrote the code shown below. It is working, but not in the way I wanted:

```
def index(filepath, keyword):

    with open(filepath) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            matches = [k for k in keyword if k in line]
            if matches:
                result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(matches), lineno)
                print(result)
                print (line)

index('deneme.txt', ['elma'])
```

Output is as follows:

```
elma            15
Sogan+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj turunçgil+Noun+A3pl ihracat+Noun+P3sg+Dat devlet+Noun destek+Noun+P3sg ver+Verb+Pass+Prog2+Cop .+Punc
```

So far so good, But when I enter a keyword like `"Sog"` it also finds the `Sogan` but I don't want that, I only want to check tokens between whitespaces. I think I need to write regex for this and I got one but I couldn't now how can i add that regex to this code.

```
r'[\w+]+'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use the word boundary marker `\b`. This is an empty match for transitions between `\w` and `\W`. If you want your keywords to be literal strings, you will have to [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) them first. You can combine everything into one regular expression using `|`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, keyword)) + r')\b')
```

OR

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?' + '|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in keyword) + r')\b')
```

Computing the matches is a bit easier now, since you can use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) instead of making your own comprehension:

```
matches = pattern.finditer(line)
```

Since each match is enclosed in a group, printing is not much more difficult:

```
result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(m.group() for m in matches), lineno)
```

OR

```
result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(map(re.Match.group(), matches)), lineno)
```

Of course, don't forget to

```
import re
```

**Corner Case**

If you have keywords that are subsets of each other with the same prefix, make sure the longer ones come first. For example, if you have

```
keyword = ['foo', 'foobar']
```

The regex will be

```
\b(foo|foobar)\b
```

When you encounter a line with `foobar` in it, `foo` will match successfully against it and then fail against `\b'. This is documented behavior of`|`. The solution is to pre-sort all your keywords by decreasing length before constructing the expression:

```
keywords.sort(key=len, reversed=True)
```

Or, if non-list inputs are possible:

```
keywords = sorted(keywords, key=len, reversed=True)
```

If you don't like this order, you can always print them in some other order after you match.

Comment: Your pattern field is giving error, I think there is some error with the the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex:

```
import re

lines = [
    'Sogan+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj turunçgil+Noun+A3pl ihracat+Noun+P3sg+Dat devlet+Noun destek+Noun+P3sg ver+Verb+Pass+Prog2+Cop .+Punc',
    'Sog+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj turunçgil+Noun+A3pl ihracat+Noun+P3sg+Dat devlet+Noun destek+Noun+P3sg ver+Verb+Pass+Prog2+Cop .+Punc',
]

keywords = ['Sog']
pattern = re.compile('(\w+)\+')

for lineno, line in enumerate(lines):
    words = set(m.group(1) for m in pattern.finditer(line))  # convert to set for efficiency
    matches = [keyword for keyword in keywords if keyword in words]
    if matches:
        result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(matches), lineno)
        print(result)
        print(line)
```

**Output**

```
Sog             1
Sog+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj turunçgil+Noun+A3pl ihracat+Noun+P3sg+Dat devlet+Noun destek+Noun+P3sg ver+Verb+Pass+Prog2+Cop .+Punc
```

**Explanation**

The pattern `'(\w+)\+'` any group of letters followed by a `+` character, `+` is special character so you need to escape it, in order to match. Then use group to extract the matching group, (i.e. the group of letters).

**Further**

1. Regular expression [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**:  a keyword like "Sog" it also finds the Sogan ... I only want tokens between whitespaces. ... how can i add that regex to this code.

Build a `regex` with your `keywords`, use the `or |` separator for multiple `keywords`.

For example:

```
import re

def index(lines, keyword):
    rc = re.compile(".*?(({})\+.+?\s)".format(keyword))

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        match = rc.match(line)
        if match:
            print("lines[{}] match:{}\n{}".format(i, match.groups(), line))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines = [
    'Sogan+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elmaro+Noun ve+Conj ... (omitted for brevity)',
    'Sog+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj ... (omitted for brevity)',
]
    index(lines, 'elma')
    index(lines, 'Sog|elma')
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> lines[1] match:('elma+Noun ', 'elma')
> Sog+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj ... (omitted for brevity)
> lines[1] match:('Sog+Noun ', 'Sog')
> Sog+Noun ,+Punc domates+Noun ,+Punc patates+Noun ,+Punc elma+Noun ve+Conj ... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***